# What is the nomenclature or theory for determining an overall status of multiple enumerations?

Tags: terminology, functional-programming

I am writing a method which evaluates multiple status enumerations and determines an overall status. **I'm looking for what this process might be called and perhaps some theory on it.**

It may be best to provide an example. Consider an alarm system, where individual sensors report one of three states:

- Alarm
- Safe
- Unknown

If any individual sensor reports `Alarm`, the state of the *entire* system might be considered to be `Alarm`. Depending on design requirements, if any sensor reports `Unknown` the overall system state might also be `Unknown` or `Alarm`.

Is there an article or encyclopedia entry that discusses the above process of evaluation? What is this type of processing called?

Comment: Sounds like an awfully specific notion to have a "name".  Rather than asking for a "name", it's usually better to state the problem you want to solve -- ask some specific question you'd like to know the answer to.  Suppose you knew a "name" for it.  What would you do with the name?  What problem would that help you solve?  I'm guessing you're asking for a name to help you search for a solution to some problem.

Comment: @D.W. Yes, just looking for associated names to perhaps name the classes/methods that perform this more accurately. Currently some are `AggregateStatus` which perhaps is okay, but I also was curious about general theory as well.